# How can I add a library folder to Spark's classpath

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar

I know one can use the `--jars` option with `spark-submit`, but in that case, I have to give full paths for all the files. Isn't there a simpler way where I can just put all my jar files in a folder and submit the whole folder?

Comment: you could use `--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=<directory_with_jars>/* --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=<directory_with_jars>/*` with spark-submit

Comment: Works fine on Linux, but I am having problem on Windows. I didn't try your suggestion but add paths in spark.default.conf. But I guess I would have the same problem with spark-submit as well.